# Are portable 2.5 inch external hard drives more prone to internal damage?

Tags: hard-disk, data-storage, backup

I bought a 2 TB external hard drive from Seagate and on the first day it stopped working. Probably something broken inside. I never had expected that it will get damaged so easily.

So I'm reconsidering my decision to buy a new storage. Basically I need to store less frequently used data I have in case I need it in future. I want it for long term.

Also I'm surprised even when I handle my laptops roughly sometimes, it doesn't affect my laptop disks at all. They work fine. Maybe they use something better?

Should I try bigger like 3.5" hard drives? Would they be more safe?

Another decision would be to buy SSD but I really can't afford that.

**So, given all that, are there any other external hard drives that are less prone to damage? Maybe size of disk also matters?**

Also, I don't need something eye catchy. I don't care how it looks from outside. I want a reliable storage for long term and something that won't stop working so easily. I feels like a really big loss when you buy something new and it gets damaged on its first day. I hope you understand my dilemma.

Comment: If you need it to be USB-powered, then you cannot use 3.5" disks. They need a 12v rail that USB doesn't have, so need an external power supply. 2.5" & SSD don't need this 12v rail, the standard 5v that USB can provide is sufficient.

Comment: @Tetsujin ah I didn't know. So 3.5 is out of question for me.

Comment: You'd need an enclosure with an external power supply.

Comment: But note that there are many ways to wreck an external drive without physically breaking it. Sudden disconnect whilst writing, power outage, disconnect without correct unmount - especially if you're not using a journaled file system. For this, NTFS just about qualifies as journaled, FAT & ExFAT don't.

Comment: @Tetsujin my portable hard drive stopped working because accidently, USB moved when I was moving my laptop and copying process got frozen. I was copying around 200GB in a one go. Could that be a reason of that damage?

Comment: Yup. That's a sure way to kill your drive. It might not be totally dead, you just killed the formatting/file system.

Comment: @Tetsujin it isn't working at all now. It just gets listed in my Device and Printers. But you can't do anything with it. If you select any option system will hang. Nor it is listed in Disk Management/Diskpart.

To confirm, I tried on Windows 7 and Ubuntu on a different laptop. They also didn't list it anywhere. It's just making a low beeping noise constantly whenever I plug it. Something is probably stuck.

Comment: I can't really help any further. It's the kind of thing I'd need in my hand to fully test. I can often force them back to life from a Mac, or at least see exactly what failed. You could try sending it back - don't tell then you broke it ;)) [This one of those times it's great if you used Amazon Prime - amazon will take anything back, you don't have to deal with the seller at all, Amazon just give you the money back then argue with the seller themselves ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah there's no option. Already created return with exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any size drive will have the same size and plastic making up the SATA connector (power and data).   Or SAS connector.

Unless you break that connector, which 99% of the time is poor user judgement plugging or removing cables, nothing out there is different.

A 3.5" drive will be a traditional spinning hard drive, and while they are pretty tough I've dropped them in the parking lot with no ill effects, they will never be as robust as a 2.5" ***S**olid **S**tate **D**isk*  that has no moving parts.

After that don't leave it like on a car dashboard in summer to cook to 180°F, they typically don't like that.

*I bought a 2 TB external hard drive from Seagate and on the first day it stopped working.*

It happens.  Warranty replace it, and move on.